# Unable to load external file in DCC

Tags: python

I am trying to load a script inside an dcc app(Autodesk Maya). Below is the code, when I execute it inside the app script editor it works fine, but when trying to load as external file it doesn't show the interface, although is loading the script fine.

I believe is related to the `if __name__ == "__main__":` part, since i never used this workflow before.

Thank you.

```
class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=maya_main_window()):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('My Window')
        self.setMinimumWidth(435)
        self.setMinimumHeight(500)


#(...)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        test_dialog.close()
        test_dialog.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass

    test_dialog = TestDialog()
    test_dialog.show()
```

Loading in app

```
from importlib import reload

import hdri_browser_script_v1
reload(hdri_browser_script_v1)
```

Comment: Is your filename is `hdri_browser_script_v1` of above code which has class `TestDialog`?

Comment: My file is named "hdri_browser_script_v1.py" @GodWin

Comment: I changed it to `if __name__ == "hdri_browser_script_v1":` and it works now. Not sure if this is the correct way tho!

Comment: No if you are going to import that file and use it in another then you should not use `__name__=="__main__"`. It means that file can be executed if it's directly executed or else if it's imported then `if` condition will be `False`. Read [Doc](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__name__-special-variable-python/#:~:text=If%20the%20source%20file%20is,name%20of%20the%20current%20module.) It explains clearly.